# Can't read a file in google colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

Can't read a file in google colaboratory .
I have .ipynb file and .csv files in the same directory but when I try to run:

```
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'train.csv' does not exist
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I hope you have run this code before opening your `train` file.

## Part I

`# Install a Drive FUSE wrapper.
 # https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
 !add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null 
 !apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
 !apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse`

## Part II

`# Generate auth tokens for Colab`

`from google.colab import auth 
 auth.authenticate_user()`

## Part III

`# Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library.`

`from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials 
 creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
 import getpass 
 !google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
 vcode = getpass.getpass() 
 !echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}`

## Part IV

`# Create a directory and mount Google Drive using that directory.`

`!mkdir -p drive
 !google-drive-ocamlfuse drive`

## Part V

`print ('Files in Drive:')
 !ls drive/`

After implementing the above codes just open your `train` file in `google-colaboratory`

`train = pd.read_csv('drive/...{folder_name}.../train.csv, encoding='utf8')`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I use windows 10 and this worked perfectly for me. Give it try.

Add new folder into your drive. Name it what you want. In my case I named it **"Colab Notebook"**. This is folder where I keep my codes and data file.

First you need to mount your drive. For this run the following one by one

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

After second command it pops link where the authentication key is. Open this link copy the key, paste and press enter.

Now type `!ls` it has to give something like this `drive  sample_data`

Upload your data file. Either it will be csv or excel file does not matter, but commands will be different for each.

**For csv file**

```
train = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebook/train.csv')
```

**For excel file** it's the same just change pandas command and file extension

Comment: i did the above commands but i face with this error : FileNotFoundError: File b'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebook/train.csv' does not exist

Comment: sorry for late answer, was too busy. When you mounted your drive did you get this? `Mounted at /content/drive/` I mean when you copy and paste authentication code.

Comment: I tested again with these settings and works perfectly. I don't know what happened in your case. Did you solve or still have problems?

Comment: yeas i still got the same error. although the Mounted at /content/drive/ message showed up to me at all

Comment: I have the same problem. Try this comand: !cp /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebook/train.csv sample_data/ 

Now use this comand: train = pd.read_csv('sample_data/train.csv')

Work for me!

Comment: [Jaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14751233) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66630571) saying "Remember to escape the spaces in the file path, e.g.: `train = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebook/train.csv')`"

Answer (score 4):

## Install the PyDrive wrapper & import libraries.

## This only needs to be done once per notebook.

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

## Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.

## This only needs to be done once per notebook.

```
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

## Download a file based on its file ID.

## A file ID looks like: laggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz

```
file_id = 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FILE_ID'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'1BH-rffqv_1auzO7tdubfaOwXzf278vJK'}) # replace the id with id of file you want to access
downloaded.GetContentFile('xyz.csv')  

# Read file as panda dataframe
import pandas as pd
xyz = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks , as I understand , completion of the authorization process,
and mounting the google drive should be done after every login and no way to skip that process ?

Comment: Yeah that's true!

Comment: Use `downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'1BH-rffqv_1auzO7tdubfaOwXzf278vJK'})` # replace the id with id of file you want to access
`downloaded.GetContentFile('xyz.csv')  `

#3. Read file as panda dataframe
`import pandas as pd`
`xyz = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')`

Answer (score 3):

make sure you put a / in the beginning of the path.
Whey you copy path by right click on your mounted drive from the file explorer, it does not copy the beginning forward slash. make sure you add it in the path.

[image: gdrive path]