# Access to local folder with Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to make a deep learning system on Colab.
My data are stored in a local folder on my laptop but I don't know how to acceed it.

When I do this, it gives me an error :

```
import os
output = [dI for dI in os.listdir(main_folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(main_folder,dI))]
print (output)

[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

`main_folder` is a local path : `C:/.../.../`

Comment: Looks like an official documentation page for this is now maintained: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Answer (score 11):

One option to access local files is to use Colab with a local install of Jupyter. Instructions to do that are here:

http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Another option is to install [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) on your local machine, put the files there, and then mount your Drive files on Colab using the following snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

After that, your Drive files will appear in the built-in file browser. For example,
[image]

Comment: I guess with the google drive way, you'd load the files in the notebook's code a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940120/1509695

Comment: I tried what was in the manual, got the link, connected locally and did a os.listdir(...) and it worked the first time.  Then it said, 
       PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/esfandiar/...'
This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: There is now also a way to mount Google Drive straight from the UI without issuing any commands.