# Connect google colab to Drive connected to my local computer

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, disk, drive

So I've connected my google drive to my local computer and when I started up google colab and connected my drive to it, it only said Drive > MyDrive instead of there being Drive > MyDrive & Computer.

How do I do this? I want the files that google colab generates to go from google drive directly to my local computer. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refect to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223136/google-colab-access-machines-local-drives-directly-using-os-listdir

Comment: I want to make colab acces my local disk to put things on it. Not put things on colab.

Comment: Here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540775/access-to-local-folder-with-colab